# How do I minify my CSS files when compile my SASS files using Sencha CMD

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-cmd

We are using Sencha Ext JS and I'm creating a custom theme using their SASS variables. I'm able to run `sencha package build` and output my theme as one big css file. But I was under the impression I could also have it output as a compressed minified version.

I've look through the docs but it appears I've missed something.

Comment: When I call `sencha app build production` (not sure whether you have to use `sencha package build production`?), I get a minified version.

Comment: Opps, I haven't been using the `app build production` command. So what's the diff with that and `build package`?

Comment: I am at home now, don't have Cmd here. `sencha app help` or `sencha help` should clarify which command is for what. I *believe* "package" is for package and "app" is for app, and there should different targets available. if you look into `.sencha` folder, you will find setting files for different targets, which you can customize to your needs. Not sure which targets there are for package, but for an app, there are development, testing and production, and only production does the minification. Of course you can override that default in the aforementioned settings file...